# Self signed certificate in Wildfly doesn't work, but works on spring-boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, wildfly, self-signed

So I have the following abridged piece of code

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","/opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/configuration/server.keystore");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword","password");
System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2");


ServiceOrder serviceOrder = new ServiceOrder();
ServiceOrderInterface orderInterface = serviceOrder.getServiceOrderPort(new AddressingFeature());
BindingProvider bindingProvider = (BindingProvider)orderInterface;
bindingProvider.getRequestContext().put(
BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY,"https://remoteservice:8095/service-order");
SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSLv3");

KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType() );
char[] password = "password".toCharArray();
ks.load(new FileInputStream("/opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/configuration/server.keystore"), password );
kmf.init( ks, password );
sc.init( kmf.getKeyManagers(), null, null );
bindingProvider.getRequestContext().put("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.https.client.SSLSocketFactory",sc.getSocketFactory() );
System.out.println("################");
System.out.println(System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore"));
System.out.println("################");
orderInterface.createServiceOrder(soapRequest);
```

It's running on an deployment in a Wildfly in a docker container trying to connect to another container called `remoteservice`. `remoteservice` is using a self-signed certificate which is imported into the `server.keystore`

When I try to run it I get

```
2020-10-01 17:19:02,718 INFO  [stdout] (externalChangesListenerContainer-1) ################
2020-10-01 17:19:02,718 INFO  [stdout] (externalChangesListenerContainer-1) /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/configuration/server.keystore
2020-10-01 17:19:02,718 INFO  [stdout] (externalChangesListenerContainer-1) ################
2020-10-01 17:19:02,747 WARNING [org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain] (externalChangesListenerContainer-1) Interceptor for {http://group.redacted.com/contract/vbs/service/service-order/v1}ServiceOrder#{http://group.redacted.com/contract/vbs/service/service-order/v1}CreateServiceOrder has thrown exception, unwinding now: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not send Message.
        ...
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: SSLHandshakeException invoking https://remoteserver:8095/service-order: Remote host closed connection during handshake
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.mapException(HTTPConduit.java:1390)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1374)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:658)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
        ... 18 more
```

If i take this piece of code and create a spring-boot empty app and just paste it in and run it using

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

or I compile it and run it with java -jar

```
mvn clean package spring-boot:repackage
java -jar target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

it just works without any issues and I can validated in on `remoteservice` that it communicates without any issues.

```
################
/opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/configuration/server.keystore
################
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.378s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Oct 01 17:34:36 UTC 2020
[INFO] Final Memory: 26M/495M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[root@ef99b6ef3b60 demo]# java -jar target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

What I can't understand what can be wrong for the code not to work on wildfly

I've added it to wildfly to no avail

```
=========================================================================
  JBoss Bootstrap Environment
  JBOSS_HOME: /opt/jboss/wildfly
  JAVA: /usr/lib/jvm/java/bin/java
  JAVA_OPTS:  -server -Xms64m -Xmx1G -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1G -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/configuration/server.keystore -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=welcome1 -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman,org.jboss.logmanager -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n -Xbootclasspath/p:/opt/jboss/wildfly/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/logmanager/main/jboss-logmanager-2.0.7.Final.jar -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager -javaagent:/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/jmx_prometheus_javaagent.jar=47111:/opt/jboss/wildfly/domain/configuration/jmx_exporter.yaml
=========================================================================
```

Comment: Probaby wildfly is running a jre that is not having that certicate. You might need to add it to cacerts

Comment: @FedericoPiazza shouldn't `System.out.println(System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore"));` alert me to that?

Comment: not sure. But i'm pretty sure you need to add the certificate in wildfly. Take a look at this link http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-security/complete-tutorial-for-configuring-ssl-https-on-wildfly

Comment: I don't think that link fits the problem since it's for exposing your own wildfly with SSL

Comment: **This is not a certificate problem.** While setting the `javax.net.ssl` sysprops in code may not work if any other code in the JVM has touched the relevant classes, you also did the config, and more important no problem with the local truststore can ever cause the 'Remote host' (i.e. server) to close prematurely. Best approach is look at the _server_ application and maybe system logs; if that's not possible, run with sysprop `javax.net.debug=ssl:handshake` to see exactly what your JSSE client side is sending and receiving, and where in the protocol sequence the problem occurs.

Comment: I am with the same problema. Can you resolving?